# IntelliJ JPA Console can't use JNDI Reference in Tomcat (or Database Source)

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, jndi

I've setup a development environment that uses Tomcat. To enable multiple data environments I've utilized JNDI to reference data sources within my project.

However, when I attempt to use the JPA Console during development in IntelliJ, it errors out:

```
[2017-01-20 10:01:54] org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[2017-01-20 10:01:54] org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/AS400]
[2017-01-20 10:01:54] java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: JNDI service is disabled
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer$Jndi.invoke(RemoteServer.java:148)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:505)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:118)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:95)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.JpaFacadeImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(JpaFacadeImpl.java:16)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[2017-01-20 10:01:54]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The key feature of this is **`JNDI service is disabled`**. Which makes total sense, since the JNDI connection is stored on the Tomcat server (`server.xml` and `context.xml`).

Is there any way I can utilize both connections without storing credentials in my `presistence.xml`?

The only way I can get it to work right now is by switching out my `persistence.xml` file between commented and uncommented code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Messaging">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.ooida.entities.TrumpiaList</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- For using hibernate with JNDI on Tomcat -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/AS400" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect" />

            <!-- For using hibernate with JNDI in the JPA/Hibernate Console -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:as400://server:port"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Have you found a nice solution? For me even commenting JNDI source name and adding direct connection doesn't help.

Comment: Still no, however I've ran into this issue from time to time.  Usually the connection is lost in the Databases panel in Intellij, if I reconnect to the data source there I can usually use the regular connection names in the hibernate file; and commenting out when I move over to Tomcat.